# Durable activity sometimes detected as Non-Deterministic workflow

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

when executing my durable function, an activity is sometimes detected as Non-Deterministic workflow, sometimes not. I cannot find the reason for.
Message: „Non-Deterministic workflow detected: TaskScheduledEvent: 4 TaskScheduled Activity_updatelogTransferDetailsStatus“

The orchestrator is doing a foreach loop. First, it calls an activity to do an update on a SQL Server database. Then a sub orchestrator task is called to some other stuff. This sub orchestrators should run in parallel per loop.
I’m counting the calls of the suborchestrators. If MAX_ACTIVITIES is reached, it will wait for completion of all parallel sub orchestrators an den execution ContinueAsNew for the Orchestrator.

**Orchestrator**:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Orchestrator_StartTransfer))]
public static async Task Orchestrator_StartTransfer([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    TransferRunSetting setting = context.GetInput<TransferRunSetting>();
    List<Task> parallelFolderTasks = new List<Task>();
    //...some code ...//
    foreach (Tbl_logTransferDetails folder in folders)
    {
        string Tablename = folder.Tablename;
        int DetailStatus = folder.DetailStatus;
        long TransferDetailId = folder.TransferDetailId;

        //Activity for update in database:
        await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(Activity_updatelogTransferDetailsStatus), (Tablename, DetailStatus, TransferDetailId));

        //run sub orchestrator in parallel
        Task task = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof(SubOrchestrator_TransferFolder), folder);
        //List of parallel tasks:
        parallelFolderTasks.Add(task);

        activityCounter++;

        //if MAX_ACTIVITIES reached, wait for Tasks, then ContineAsNew:
        if (activityCounter % MAX_ACTIVITIES == 0)
        {
            //wait to completion of all parallel tasks:
            await Task.WhenAll(parallelFolderTasks);
            //then Orchestrator ContinueAsNew:
            context.ContinueAsNew(setting);
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(parallelFolderTasks.ToArray());
}
```

After ContinueAsNew several replays where executed an running fine. Then suddenly I got the failure „Non-Deterministic workflow detected: TaskScheduledEvent: 4 TaskScheduled **Activity_updatelogTransferDetailsStatus**“. Before everything is running fine ….

**Activity**

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Activity_updatelogTransferDetailsStatus))]
public static async Task Activity_updatelogTransferDetailsStatus([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context, ILogger log)
{
    (string Tablename, int DetailStatus, long TransferDetailId) = context.GetInput<(string, int, long)>();
    //Call async Task to update database table:
    await LoggingTransfer.updatelogTransferDetailsStatus(Tablename, DetailStatus, TransferDetailId);
}
```

**Async Task to do the update on database**

```
public static async Task updatelogTransferDetailsStatus(string Tablename, int DetailStatus, long TransferDetailId)
{
    string query = "UPDATE dbo.bkp_logTransferDetails" +
                        "   SET DetailStatus =" + DetailStatus +
                        " WHERE TransferDetailId =" + TransferDetailId;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea, why execution oft he acitvity runs fine all the time and then suddenly is detected as Non-Deterministic?

Comment: What is the reason to run the  orchestrator as `context.ContinueAsNew`?

Comment: What is the code for finding folders? Also ContinueAsNew only tells the orchestrator to restart when the orchestrator finishes. The way its used now doesnt make alot of sense.

Comment: These are only code snippets. Before foreach (at position of comment //...some code ...//) the list of folders is read from database (separate activity). Content of this list respectiely content of DB source table for folders to be read does not change during execution of the durable function.

Comment: Im guessing you are not changing MAX_ACTIVITIES anywhere aswell. Are you running multiple function apps with the same storage account? Example prod/qa app

Comment: Yes, MAX_ACTIVITIES doen't change anywhere. The function is not deployed to Azure, I run it for testing locally on Visual Studio. It uses an own storage account, even during my local tests in VS. Before running a test, I drop anything in the storage account to avoid interferences from old runs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code that changes on [replays of the orchestration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#reliability). Also check the set of documented [code constraints for orchestrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints).

Any code from your orchestration should always return the same result. And check the replaying [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics?tabs=python#app-logging)

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    logging.info("Calling F1.")
    yield context.call_activity("F1")
    logging.info("Calling F2.")
    yield context.call_activity("F2")
    logging.info("Calling F3.")
    yield context.call_activity("F3")
    return None

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

to check the code that is required for logging. The trick is just to check `context.is_replaying` in your code which can skip certain code during replays.

for more information check the related discussion in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/454684/non-deterministic-workflow-detected-in-durable-fun.html).